# Getting error when null value received in PowerApps calling the User Profile service

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, powerapps

I've been building a sort of people search app in powerapps using the org browser template made by MS and it works nicely but I'm keep having on issue that I wasn't able to find a solution for anywhere on the net.

As part of the search I'm fetching user photo from azure AD through the Office365Users connector but when there isn't any photo and the call returns NULL there is an error displayed to the user.

I tested a bit and seems to be a thing anytime I call something using this connector that returns null. I get that there is warning in the designer when null is returned but why is it showing to users and how to get rid of it.

I tried to put validation in place checking if there is an image and if not to display a placeholder but the check it self is what triggers the error.

```
Office365Users.UserPhoto(EmployeeId)
```

This is the call I'm doing and here are samples of the error:

[Win10 Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNR2N.png)

[iOs powerapps app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQgyT.png)